# JBOSS JMX/RMI monitoring through firewall - ports setup

Tags: rmi, jmx, firewall

There are two main initial steps to tick for this to work:

- exposing RMI adding following properties to the JBOSS startup script

  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
- making RMI behave and be firewall friendly https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJBossBehindAFirewall

My doubt is on .jmxremote.port being the same or a different port as

```
<attribute name="RmiPort">1098</attribute>
```

Comment: The 'JNP invoker listening port' and the JMX port are for completely different purposes.

Comment: Thanks EJP, couldn't find any doc/link both explaining how to expose RMI and configure forcing it to be firewall friendly. The found docs mention to do both configs separately

Answer (score 0):

Below sets the RMI registry port, which is 1900 by default.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
```

And below sets the random RMI port to a fixed port.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12346
```

Tested on Java 8 and a Tomcat process and a Spring-Boot(tomcat embedded) process through a firewall.